# Relation between instant power and electric-magnetic power in a series RLC circuit

Tags: power, electromagnetism, passive-networks

I know that the instant power of a circuit is given by the product of the voltage and the current of a circuit while the expression for the electric and magnetic energies is: $$
W(t)=W_e(t)+W_h(t)=\frac{1}{2}v_{C_1}^2(t)C_1+\frac{1}{2}i_{L_g}^2(t)L_g
$$
My circuit is the following:
[image]

The values of the components for my circuit are:
$$C_1=31.66nF$$
$$R_g=5000\Omega$$
$$L_g=320H$$
$$V_g=311\cdot\sin(100\pi t)$$
In this first image, the red graph is the power delivered by the voltage source, the green graph the power disipated by the resistor and the blue graph the difference between both (I was told to represent this specific graphs)
[image]

While the electric-magnetic energy is given by this yellow graph (just substituting the values of the components above):
[image]

I am trying to find a relationship between both types of energies, but I do not see a correlation between them. Maybe that both tend to a defined value when the transient finishes? However, the magnitudes are very different. Does anyone know a better approach for that question?

Comment: You forgot the power from R and then understand rise time from X/R ratios or R/X depending if in series or parallel that give you a rise time of ~270ms.. Impedance ratios in this case overdamped Q<1

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The instant power from R is the green graph. Since my circuit does not change frecuency (50Hz) the values for the capacitor and the inductor I have used are the ones that make the impedances to cancel each other at a certain time, if that information is useful

Comment: Your graphs are totally ambiguous and your quest is oddly written. Speak plainly please.